# Sudo caching on compilation mode

Tags: shell-command, compilation-mode, sudo

There is a command I run very often using `compile` that must be run as sudo. I wanted to achieve something similar to the 5min caching of sudo in a shell: if I keep running the command in intervals shorter than 5min it does not prompts me for the password again.

Is there an easy way to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you are using Tramp's `sudo` method to run the command with root permissions from Emacs. With a very recent snapshot of Tramp 2.4.1-pre (or 27.0.50), there is a new configuration parameter to the sudo method, called `tramp-session-timeout`. It defaults to 300 seconds, and shall behave as you like.

Comment: I was literally runing `C-u M-x compile RET sudo myscript.sh`. I just took a quick look at tramp (I have never used it). Do you mean doing something like this?
`(let ((default-directory "/sudo::/path/to/script")) (compile "myscript.sh"))`

Comment: Yes, something like this.